# How to make the data displayed on VB6 textbox not disappear

Tags: vb6

I have problem in my VB6.. I'm using timer for the data to be displayed in the textbox..But the problem is the data disappear after a few seconds..How to make this data remain in the textbox until i click the command button to measure another data? 
The coding for the timer:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
   ipt = MSComm1.Input
   ipt = Right(ipt, 4)
   Text1.Text = ipt
End Sub
```

Please help me..

Comment: kill the timer after first execution or debug your procedure so that when it is called what value it set in text box.

Answer (score 4):

```
Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
    ipt = MSComm1.Input
    ipt = Right(ipt, 4)

    if len(ipt) > 0 then
        Text1.Text = ipt
    end if
End Sub
```

Comment: @nurul - don't forget to mark the answer if you are happy with it